# passing data back to a previously allocated UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have a view controller that then has a button that passes to an option menu.

When options are set they need to be past back to the previously allocated viewcontroller.

How is this possible without 'alloc and init another' instance of the object?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using a delegate protocol. First view controller should become the delegate of the second view controller and then you can call this delegate method in your first view controller once the selection is done.

You can lookup google for implementation of delegates in objective-c. Its pretty simple. Add a

```
@protocol <delegatename>
<declare delegate method>
@end
```

Create a member variable in the second view controller for assigning the delegate. And define the method in the class implementing the delegate.

Comment: Although the other answers may seem simpler, this is *the* way to go if you really want to follow the SDK's principles.

Comment: Ok well custom delegation is completely new to me. I've spent the last hour trying to get my head round it.... Can you throw me a few lines of code simple explaining what is talking to what... because this is where i'm getting completely confused.

Comment: I just wrote a blog post on that. Read it at www.iprav.in

Answer (score 0):

When you `init` your option viewController, pass it a reference to its parent.

I.E.

```
[[OptionViewController alloc] initWith...: parent:];
```

Use a `@property` or a method or somesuch to call on the parent to pass the data back.

Comment: You could also pass a reference to some info holder object that the parent has access to, and could reference in its `viewWillAppear:` callback.

Comment: ok so i allocate the object with a parent. surely the parent of that allocated object will be the object that is allocating it (self)

Comment: Correct. So:`[[OptionViewController alloc] initWith...: parent:self];`

Comment: messageOptions = [[MessageOptions alloc] initWithNibName:@"MessageOptions" bundle:nil parent:self]; 

i get this error

file://localhost/Users/jonathan%20pink/Desktop/2sms%20v2.0/twosmsapp/twosmsapp/SendSMS.m: warning: Semantic Issue: Method '-initWithNibName:parent:bundle:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Comment: You would need to define your own initializer. If you don't want to do that, you could set up a `delegate` property as the other answer suggests, and just call `optionVC.delegate = self;` after initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a shared singleton?
http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html

Or save the parameters to nsuserdefaults and read them back in in your first viewcontroller

or some other temporary store such as your appdelegate

I've used all three of the above approaches before.

Comment: Globals (such as singletons or using the AppDelegate) would need to be refactored back out of the code if the parent controller can exist in multiple stacks w/in the application at one time, though.